# empty sharepoint user profile property throw an exception

Tags: sharepoint

I have a user profile property. user not assigned any value that property. If I use below code. It is thorwing exception " object reference not set to an instance of an object "

```
userprof["OptOut"].ToString()
```

I tried all types 
like

```
if (userprof["OptOut"] != null)
          OR
if(userprof["OptOut"].Value != null)
```

nothing worked out for me.

Here userProf object has value. userprof["OptOut"].Value  is null

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You must check it like this:

```
if (userprof["OptOut"][0] != null)
```

I use this method:

```
    private string GetPropertyValue(UserProfile userProfile, string propertyName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userProfile[propertyName][0] == null)
                {
                 //code like this:
                 //return "'" + propertyName + "' value is null";
                }

            return userProfile[propertyName].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         //code like this:
         //return string.Format("Error with '{0}' UP-property: {1}", propertyName, ex.Message);
        }
        return "-";
    }
```